# Consulta traz os dados ignorando $conditions

Tags: cakephp

Estou fazendo uma consulta e o cake está trazendo todos os datos ignorando $conditions. Quero buscar por data, mas quando coloco uma data que não existe em nenhum registro, mesmo assim tráz todos os dados.

```
public function consultarDespesa() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $dataDespesa=null;

        $dataDespesa = $this->request->data['Despesa']['ano']."-".$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes'];

        $despesas = $this->Despesa->find('all', array(
'conditions'=>array(
    'data_despesa like'=>"%$this->dataDespesa%")));

        if (($despesas==null) || (!isset($despesas))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Sua pesquisa não retornou nenhum resultado.");
        }

        else {
            $this->Session->write("Despesas", $despesas);

            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'exibirDespesas'));
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.hastebin.com/aluridixiq.coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta comparando data com o `LIKE`, nesse caso não vai te retornar nenhum registro, pois nenhum registro esta igual a data que você esta buscando.

Quando for comprar data de um determinado dia você pode usar `>=` e `<=`,  `between` ou outras formas de comparar datas.

Fiz com maior e igual

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'data_despesa >='=>"%$this->dataDespesa%",
        'data_despesa <='=>"%$this->dataDespesa%"
        )   
    ));
```

Edit - Tenta comparar dessa forma:

```
$despesas = $this->Despesa->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'MONTH(data_despesa)'=>$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes'],
        'YEAR(data_despesa)'=>$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano']
        )   
    ));
```

Comment: É verdade, mas depende de como a data está gravada no banco.

Comment: @Jeferson Assis Estou usando like porque só quero tomar como argumento o mês e o ano, o dia não me interessa. O like funciona, pois fiz com query e só trazia quando encontrava. E na conversão do cake, está ignorando o operador, trazendo tudo como se fosse um select *

Comment: Alterei a resposta e coloquei um complemento, tenta da segunda forma

Comment: @AndréNascimento Essa data está no seu banco de dados como `DATETIME` ou `VARCHAR`?

Comment: !Jeferson Assis funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Altere isto:

```
'data_despesa like'=>"%$this->dataDespesa%"
```

para:

```
"data_despesa like '%{$this->dataDespesa}%'"
```